# Debian 10 only boots to GRUB (LUKS + LVM)

Tags: debian, lvm, grub, prompt, luks

On reboot, my new installation of Debian 10 (amd64) only spits out a GRUB shell. The operating system is not loading.
My disk is GPT, with the first parititon being ESP (/dev/sda1), formatted FAT32 with both 'boot' and 'efi' flags set. I will also note that when mounted, /dev/sda1 shows a directory structure beginning with /EFI. I also noticed that /dev/sda1 shows up in /etc/fstab, but not in /etc/mtab.
The second (/dev/sda2) partition is an ecrypted LVM containing the root filesystem (formatted as ext4). I can unlock this partition and mount root using the CD's Rescue Mode. 
Is there a way to get my system booting, without having to run setup over again? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Answer (score 0):

Not really the solution I was looking for, but shrinking the ESP to make room for an unencrypted /boot then re-installing Debian seemed the easiest path. It was a new installation, so nothing was really lost anyways.